# What is an Acer Converter Port?

Tags: displayport, mini-displayport

What is this port "Acer Converter Port"? Is it basically the same as miniDP? Can I connect a monitor like Dell U2713H on this one?

From [Frequently Asked Questions on the Aspire R7 series](http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/30837/%7E/frequently-asked-questions-on-the-aspire-r7-series#displayport):

> **9. Can I connect a DisplayPort monitor to the Acer Converter Port?**
>
> The Acer Converter Port uses the same physical port as a Mini DisplayPort, but is designed to connect to an Acer proprietary cable. If you connect a DisplayPort monitor, Acer cannot guarantee the functionality of the monitor.
>
> No damage should occur to either monitor or notebook by connecting a Mini DisplayPort cable.

Can someone confirm this will work for sure?

Comment: Can you provide a product page that lists "Acer Converter Port" on it?

Comment: http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-V5-573G-54208G50aii-Notebook.99264.0.html I am looking at this laptop

Comment: If Acer cannot guarantee it will work then how can you expect us to guarantee it will work. If you want a gurantee it will work get a different laptop with actual Mini-Displayport standard support.

Comment: Someone with a laptop having this port and a monitor with this resolution can try it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that would bring the scope of this question outside of the bounds of this site.  Besides Acer's own documentation currently answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to essentially be a Lightning port imitator:

From your [link](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-V5-573G-54208G50aii-Notebook.99264.0.html) in the comments:

*"You also have another port at the back, the **Acer Converter port**. It looks a lot like a Lightning port with its specifications and **you can comfortably attach displays, hard drives or routers**"*

It sounds like a port with enough bandwidth to carry large amounts of data making it suitable for even displays.

It also sounds like it is something Acer has not released to market:
http://community.acer.com/t5/Notebooks-Netbooks/Who-knows-where-to-buy-Acer-Aspire-R7-port-converter/td-p/91981

The back-side of the laptop does have an HDMI Port so your monitor should be able to hook up to it.

Comment: @Ramhound Hah! Now I question the articles' accuracy as well. Never-the-less, and HDMI port should work for OPs' monitor right? Granted they have an HDMI cable of the correct revision. Looks like 1.4 supports 4K http://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmi_1_4/4K.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You use that port to connect an Acer Converter Cable (Mini CP to VGA/LAN/USB).  Mini cp is the name of that port, mini converter port.  There is also a mini cp to vga.  There will probably be other mini cp converters in the future, in order to get rid of the bigger ports.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's like a mini-Displayport and you can use it with the Dell monitor, because the Dell U2713H supports miniDisplayport.

[From the dell-website:](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=225-4148&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch)

> **Superb user experience**:
>
> Convenience is at your fingertips with
>   multiple connectivity ports, including USB 3.0, DisplayPort 1.2,
>   **mini-DisplayPort**, DVI-DL (HDCP) and HDMI.2

Comment: He will want to stick with Acer branded cables. A standard mini-DisplayPort cable might no work.

Comment: Can you confirm if this will or will not work with a miniDP monitor?

Comment: @ShadowHero - Acer's own documentation says it **MIGHT** work depending on the monitor used.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Acer V5 model laptop with this connector, and the VGA adaptor from Acer seems to work in a thunderbolt port on a Retina MacBook Pro 2013 model of my friends, so I assume it is either a Thunderbolt port, or a Mini Display Port plug, as I'm not sure whether Apple's ones are dual-purpose. It may also help that in the AMD Catalyst manager program the Dual Graphics adapter is listed as 8x, which supposedly can be run through Thunderbolt.

Answer (score 0):

Acer Converter Port works as miniDP on my Acer Aspire R7 laptop with Intel HD4000 video adapter. I can work with 2nd external full HD monitor (1920x1080) via miniDP-HDMI adapter - that's in addition to another external monitor via direct HDMI cable.
Recently I bought Acer CB280HK 4K 28" Ultra HD monitor and it can work with 4k resolution 3840x2160 up to 32Hz via this miniDP connector using a standard miniDP to DP cable.  Note that I can get 4k resolution via HDMI only up to 25Hz.

To set Intel HD4000 to work with 4k resolution via miniDP or HDMI you need to add custom resolution using Intel's CustomModeApp utility - please search internet about how to use it, for ex.  Intel site, support forums.

I used basic CustomModeApp mode to set my custom 4k resolutions and it works great - I am really happy with all my office apps:
in basic CustomModeApp mode: 
- set resolution 3840 x 2160
- set refresh rate to 25 for hdmi connection and 30 or 32 for miniDP connection
- select "CVT-RB" for the "Timing Standard" dropdown

And below is some more info about custom resolutions from Intel support forum. Good luck!

HDMI :
Intel HD4000 Max Pixel Clock supported  on HDMI is 225Mhz. So max supported is 1920 x 1080 (60p, 85p) On HDMI 
Note : 2560 x1440_ (60 Hz) is not supported on HDMI as it Exceeds the max Pixel Clock supported by our Intel 4000 Hardware ( 225Mhz)

DispalyPort :
Intel HD4000 Max Pixel Clock supported on DisplayPort is 348 Mhz
So, 2560 x1440_ 60  and 2560 x1600_ 60 is supported on DisplayPort  Interface only.

It is possible to do UHD (3840x2160P) using this chip by being careful to stay under the maximum HDMI dot clock.
Using CustomModeApp:
Front Porch  H=48  V=3
Back Porch H=80 V=23
Sync Width H=32 V=5
Active H=3840 V=2160
Scan Rate V=25

It relies on the screen supporting 24Hz refresh rates as most UHD screens will. 24Hz is used by Blue-ray in film mode.
Dot Clock for these HDMI settings is 221MHz which is below the hardware maximum of 225MHz

Advice from previous posts
Select "CVT-RB" for the "Timing Standard" dropdown

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: I have an Acer R7 and the port in question WORKS with a mac mini display port to dvi adapter connected to a standard 22 inch acer monitor. I gives ful HD with no problems. I do not know if a generic adapter will work but I think so because they mention so at amazon, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's a mini Display Port.  So you can buy an adaptor (miniDP to HDMI) to connect to an external monitor.  Still baffles me why Acer call it by a different name!

Comment: Actually its not a standard Mini-Displayport. Standard MDP cables MIGHT NOT work with this particular port. Acer of course sells converter cables that would