# Can Acer Converter Port be used as miniDP with full HD and 4K monitors

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, acer-aspire

I have Acer Aspire R7 laptop with Intel HD4000 display adapter and Acer Converter Port which looks like miniDP connector. Acer doesn't provide information about usage of this port for monitor connection. I found some info  about that port at the link below, but there are similar questions in the answers there about a possible regular miniDP functionality for monitor connection.
[What is an Acer Converter Port?](https://superuser.com/questions/664273/what-is-an-acer-converter-port)

So can Acer Converter Port be used as miniDP with full HD and 4K monitors via miniDP-HDMI adapter or via just regular miniDP-DP cable?

Please note, this question is not a duplicate of the [What is an Acer Converter Port?](https://superuser.com/questions/664273/what-is-an-acer-converter-port) question. My question is specific to the usage of this port for the regular miniDP monitor connection. There is no voted answer to this question in that thread. And I had complains in that thread trying to provide more info for this particular port usage (btw, from the same person, who now complains here)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an Acer Converter Port?](http://superuser.com/questions/664273/what-is-an-acer-converter-port)

Comment: Please note, this question is not a duplicate of the What is an Acer Converter Port? question. My question is specific to the usage of this port for the regular miniDP monitor connection. There is no voted answer to this question in that thread. And I had complains in that thread trying to provide more info for this particular port usage (btw, from the same person, who now complains here)

Comment: @VPP - That is an automatically generated comment when I flagged this as a possible duplicate.  There is no need to call me out.

Comment: the question is why did you flagged this as a possible duplicate after your "not a direct answer" comment in a possibly duplicated thread?

Comment: @VPP - Anything I say you will disagree with.  The comment that is automatically generated is my justification for the flag.  There is a reason the comment is worded the way it is.  4 other community members, have to agree this is indeed a duplicate, before this question is closed.  I just wanted to make it clear I am not complaining about anything and that the comment is submitted on my behalf when I flagged it.

Comment: @Ramhound, I believe you are doing bad things to this forum and to the whole user community. I think you don't care about usefulness of the provided info but rather take any opportunity to be visible and maybe add points to your "reputation" - I don't know how it's calculated here

Comment: @Ramhound, this is my last friendly note on this subject. You may still improve your karma voting positive to the useful posts about undocumented features - like this mine one :)

Comment: @VPP - I won't be voting on any of your contributions for awhile.  I will still flag and submit close votes though.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer to above question a year ago. Now I have my personal experience which I'd like to share here.

Acer Converter Port works as miniDP on my Acer Aspire R7 laptop with Intel HD4000 video adapter. I can work with 2nd external full HD monitor (1920x1080) via miniDP-HDMI adapter - that's in addition to another external monitor via direct HDMI cable. Recently I bought Acer CB280HK 4K 28" Ultra HD monitor and it can work with 4k resolution 3840x2160 up to 32Hz via this miniDP connector using a standard miniDP to DP cable. Note that I can get 4k resolution via HDMI only up to 25Hz.

To set Intel HD4000 to work with 4k resolution via miniDP or HDMI you need to add custom resolution using Intel's CustomModeApp utility - please search internet about how to use it, for ex. Intel site, support forums.

I used basic CustomModeApp mode to set my custom 4k resolutions and it works great - I am really happy with all my office and photo editing apps.

Settings for 4k custom resolutions in basic CustomModeApp mode:

- set resolution 3840 x 2160
- set refresh rate to 25 for hdmi connection and 30 or 32 for miniDP connection
- select "CVT-RB" for the "Timing Standard" dropdown

And below is some more info about custom resolutions from Intel support forum. Good luck!

HDMI : Intel HD4000 Max Pixel Clock supported on HDMI is 225Mhz. So max supported is 1920 x 1080 (60p, 85p) On HDMI Note : 2560 x1440_ (60 Hz) is not supported on HDMI as it Exceeds the max Pixel Clock supported by our Intel 4000 Hardware ( 225Mhz)

DispalyPort : Intel HD4000 Max Pixel Clock supported on DisplayPort is 348 Mhz
So, 2560 x1440_ 60 and 2560 x1600_ 60 is supported on DisplayPort Interface only.

It is possible to do UHD (3840x2160P) using this chip by being careful to stay under the maximum HDMI dot clock. Using CustomModeApp: Front Porch H=48 V=3 Back Porch H=80 V=23 Sync Width H=32 V=5 Active H=3840 V=2160 Scan Rate V=25

It relies on the screen supporting 24Hz refresh rates as most UHD screens will. 24Hz is used by Blue-ray in film mode. Dot Clock for these HDMI settings is 221MHz which is below the hardware maximum of 225MHz

Advice from previous posts Select "CVT-RB" for the "Timing Standard" dropdown